# No content shows up after struggling with post Meteor 0.9.0.1 update Bootstrap 3 with Less

Tags: css, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I thought I could just install Bootstrap 3 with Less into my Meteor app real quick and move on but it's been really problematic. I'm still just learning Meteor.

I added it with

```
meteor add less
meteor add simison:bootstrap3-less
```

Then I made a file imports.less in my {app home}/client/styles/ directory. In this file I put:

```
@import "/packages/bootstrap3-less/bootstrap.import.less";
@import "/packages/bootstrap3-less/lib/less/theme.import.less";
```

But apparently that no longer works since they updated Meteor's package manager. So I followed the directions on the github issues thread(https://github.com/simison/bootstrap3-less/issues/30). And that didn't really work how they said either. I just kept getting that the compiler couldn't find the two files. Finally Meteor stopped erroring when I changed it to this:

```
@import "../css/0-bootstrap3-less/lib/less/bootstrap.import.less";
@import "../css/0-bootstrap3-less/lib/less/theme.import.less";
```

Only now when the page loads in the browser it's just a blank white screen. I didn't change the html at all. Before I started doing this I had a form and h1 line there working(but plain and ugly). I made my form using aldeed's quickform which uses bootstrap3 by default. I've used bootstrap before but never with less. I thought it would be a good time to learn a bit about it.

Anyone have any clue why not even a line of text will show up now?

#### Note:

In defense of me asking a question since anytime I do I get clobbered by everyone and end up having my question closed within about 5 seconds. Yes there are very similar questions around on SO but I think only ones Sept 2014 or later would be valid.

It seems like this is the only relevant one from after the update: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25655746/meteor-0-9-0-1-w-bootstrap3-less-not-finding-less-files Since I'm not getting the compiler errors anymore, which I think means it's finding the files now, I'm not sure if I'm still having the same problem as this question or if it's different. I don't have enough rep to comment on that question but it seems like the github issue thread they linked to never really comes to a resolution.

At this point I'm not even sure if it's an issue with me not understanding Meteor or an issue with me not understanding how to use Bootstrap with Less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i understood you are using simison:bootstrap3-less with Meteor 0.9.x. The README on github tells you:

> NOTE: This package was good for Meteor 0.6.x-0.8.x and with changes in
>   Meteor 0.9.x the method this package uses isn't working anymore.

Notice that the README has been changed since this question was asked.

For Meteor 0.9.x you should use Meteor 0.9.x [nemo64:bootstrap less](https://github.com/Nemo64/meteor-bootstrap)